# Refactored watch task using gulp v4 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm refactoring my gulpfile now I'm using gulp v4 and am having an issue with gulp watch not running my `stylesCompileIncremental` function. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

My refactoring includes:

- Switching to using functions instead of gulp.task
- Using `series` and `parallel` as per the [docs](https://gulpjs.org/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.html)
- Exporting public tasks at the bottom of my gulpfile ie `exports.stylesWatch = stylesWatch;`
- Adding callbacks in functions to tell Gulp the function is complete

The code for the affected tasks is as follows (directory paths are stored in package.json file hence pathConfig.ui... values):

```
// Compile only particular Sass file that has import of changed file
function stylesCompileIncremental(cb) {
    sassCompile({
        source: getResultedFilesList(changedFilePath),
        dest: pathConfig.ui.core.sass.dest,
        alsoSearchIn: [pathConfig.ui.lib.resources]
    });
    cb();
}

// Compile all Sass files and watch for changes
function stylesWatch(cb) {
    createImportsGraph();
    var watcher = gulp.watch(pathConfig.ui.core.sass.src + '**/*.scss', gulp.parallel(devServReloadStyles));
    watcher.on('change', function(event) {
        changedFilePath = event;
    });
    cb();
}

// reload css separated into own function. No callback needed as returning event stream
function reloadCss() {
    return gulp.src(generateFilePath)
        .pipe($.connect.reload()); // css only reload
}

function devServReloadStyles(cb) {
    gulp.series(stylesCompileIncremental, reloadCss);
    cb();
}
```

When I run `gulp stylesWatch` using my refactored code I get the below output (notice the `stylesCompileIncremental` task is not run):

[image: Refactored output]

So my watch tasking is successfully running but there's something wrong when the `devServReloadStyles` is run for the `stylesCompileIncremental` function to not kick in.

The original code before refactoring (when using gulp v3) is below:

```
// Compile only particular Sass file that has import of changed file
gulp.task('styles:compile:incremental', () => {
    return sassCompile({
        source: getResultedFilesList(changedFilePath),
        dest: pathConfig.ui.core.sass.dest,
        alsoSearchIn: [pathConfig.ui.lib.resources]
    });
});

// Compile all Sass files and watch for changes
gulp.task('styles:watch', () => {
    createImportsGraph();
    gulp.watch(
        pathConfig.ui.core.sass.src + '**/*.scss',
        ['devServ:reload:styles']
    ).on('change', event => changedFilePath = event.path);
});

// Reload the CSS links right after 'styles:compile:incremental' task is returned
gulp.task('devServ:reload:styles', ['styles:compile:incremental'], () => {
    return gulp.src(generateFilePath) // css only reload
        .pipe($.connect.reload());
});
```

The original task output when running `styles:watch` is this:

[image: Original output]

And this is the sassCompile variable used inside `stylesCompileIncremental` which I've currently not changed in anyway.

```
    /**
* Configurable Sass compilation
* @param {Object} config
*/
const sassCompile = config => {
    const sass = require('gulp-sass');
    const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
    const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

    const postProcessors = [
        autoprefixer({
            flexbox: 'no-2009'
        })
    ];

    return gulp.src(config.source)
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: true,
            largeFile: true
        }))
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: config.alsoSearchIn,
            sourceMap: false,
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            indentType: 'tab',
            indentWidth: '1',
            linefeed: 'lf',
            precision: 10,
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .on('error', function (error) {
            $.util.log('\x07');
            $.util.log(error.message);
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(postcss(postProcessors))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
};
```

**UPDATE**

This is due to an issue with my `devServReloadStyles` function, although I'm still unsure why. If I change my `stylesWatch` function to use the original `devServ:reload:styles` task `stylesCompileIncremental` gets run.

```
// Compile all Sass files and watch for changes
function stylesWatch(cb) {
    createImportsGraph();
    var watcher = gulp.watch(pathConfig.ui.core.sass.src + '**/*.scss', gulp.parallel('devServ:reload:styles'));
    watcher.on('change', function(event) {
        changedFilePath = event;
    });
    cb();
}
```

It would still be good to not use the old task and have this as a function though.
Can anybody tell me why my refactored version doesn't work and have any suggestions as to how this should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this now.
`gulp.series` and `gulp.parallel` return functions so there was no need to wrap `stylesCompileIncremental` and `reloadCss` inside another function ie. `devServReloadStyles`.
As per Blaine's comment [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1093).

So my function:

```
function devServReloadStyles(cb) {
    gulp.series(stylesCompileIncremental, reloadCss);
cb();
```

}

Can just be assigned to a variable:

```
const devServReloadStyles = gulp.series(stylesCompileIncremental, reloadCss);
```

And my stylesWatch task is already calling devServReloadStyles:

```
// Compile all Sass files and watch for changes
function stylesWatch(cb) {
    createImportsGraph();
    var watcher = gulp.watch(pathConfig.ui.core.sass.src + '**/*.scss', gulp.parallel(devServReloadStyles));
    watcher.on('change', function(event) {
        changedFilePath = event;
    });
    cb();
}
```

So running `gulp stylesWatch` now runs the `stylesCompileIncremental` job (notice how `devServReloadStyles` doesn't show as it's not a function).

[image]